# PLC or device to simulate switchgear in High Voltage substation

Tags: input, hardware, plc

I need a simple and cheap "PLC" or another device to execute very simple task based on hardware input and outputs.
The goal is to simulate "switchgear" in a high voltage power substation, breakers and disconnectors.
Basicly it gives feedback of the device when in "open or closed state" based on "open and close commands" given

There are 7 devices in a bay, so there should be:
14 inputs for commands (7 open and 7 close commands)
14 outputs for states (7 open and 7 closed states)
The hardware input and outputs should handle 220V DC.
A small monitor or LEDs to show the states would be preferable.

I know this can be done with "simple relay technique", but the relays I can find capable for this are pretty expensive and pretty huge.

I also know it can be done by programming, and here is the basic idea of the code:

```
Variable_A = 0 'There should be 7 variables, so a copy of the entire code with variables A to G

If Hardware-input 1 'open command
    Set Var_A: 0
    delay 2s 'delay to 
    Set Var_A: 1

If Hardware-input 2 'close command
    Set Var_A: 0
    delay 2s
    Set Var_A: 2

Case
    Var_A = 0   'between state
    Hardware-output1 = 0
    Hardware-output2 = 0
    Var_A = 1   'open state
    Hardware-output1 = 0
    Hardware-output2 = 1
    Var_A = 2   'closed state
    Hardware-output1 = 1
    Hardware-output2 = 0
    Var_A = 3   'illigal state
    Hardware-output1 = 1
    Hardware-output2 = 1
```

What I thought of is a Siemens DIN-rail PLC or a raspberry PI with external inputs/outputs.

So Im asking if anyone can recommend a good solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I was suggested Arduino and this seems like a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should ask this question in the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

220VDC would be very unusual for a PLC.A common PLC with 24VDC Input and output will be a cheaper option.To use conventional 24VDC PLC I/O, you could place solid state relays or opto-couplers between the field devices and the PLC.